# Почему не работает HtmlLexer в питон киви?

Tags: python, kivy

Начал изучать питон-киви от блогера Хауди Хо, видео трехлетней давности, в компиляторе при тестировании показалась ошибка

> `Cannot find reference 'HtmlLexer' in '__init__.py'`

что делать, как заставить код работать?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.codeinput import CodeInput
from pygments.lexers import HtmlLexer

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text = 'This is my first button',
                      font_size=30,
                      on_press = self.btn_press,
                      background_color = [.16,.16,.14,1],
                      background_normal = ''
                      )
        return CodeInput( Lexer = HtmlLexer())

    def btn_press(self, instance):
        print('the button was clicked')
        instance.text = 'I was cliked'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки со всем трейсбэком

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня ошибка не воспроизводится.

Основная проблема в вашем коде - работа любой функции прерывается после `return`, до второго `return` внутри метода `build` выполнение не доходит. В окне отобразится только кнопка, которую возвращает первый `return`.

Вместо нескольких `return` нужно элементы управления разместить внутри лэйаута, потом этот лэйаут вернуть через `return`. Кроме того, параметр `lexer` в `CodeInput` нужно писать с маленькой буквы.

Рабочий пример:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.codeinput import CodeInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from pygments.lexers import HtmlLexer


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        button = Button(text = 'This is my first button',
                      font_size=30,
                      on_press = self.btn_press,
                      background_color = [.16,.16,.14,1],
                      background_normal = ''
                      )
        root.add_widget(button)
        codeinput = CodeInput( lexer = HtmlLexer())
        root.add_widget(codeinput)
        return root

    def btn_press(self, instance):
        print('the button was clicked')
        instance.text = 'I was cliked'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

(html скопировал из [статьи википедии про html](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_HTML-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) и вставил в текстовое поле для демонстрации работы подсветки)

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ очень помог)